# Python 3.7 new line and slicing

Tags: python

function in python 3.7 that print any word and slicing+making new line  as explained in the next line: The function name('yesterday')  printing: y ye yes yest yeste yester yesterd yesterda yesterday (every part in new line) 
this was what I tried to do:

def yesterday():

```
str ="y\s ye\s"
    str.split("\s")                  
       ['y', 'ye',
```

'yes']
    print()

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @Ares, there's no example to show, he just expects us to give it to him... and sure enough someone will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. List splicing is what you're after.

```
def yesterday():
    for i in range(1,len("yesterday")+1):
        print("yesterday"[:i])

yesterday()
```